# Chef Knife Upload Cookbook: Method not Allowed

Tags: centos, chef, cookbook

I'm running Chef server 11 on a CentOS 6 box. Installed via the RPM from Opscode. I set up my workstation on a Windows 7 box. I can run the usual `knife client list` and get a response, so I'm confident that my server is working correctly.

I created a local Git repo on the workstation, added the [getting-started cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/getting-started), and committed it to the local repo (on local disk on the workstation).

When I try to upload the cookbook, though:

```
knife cookbook upload getting-started
Uploading getting-started [0.4.0]
ERROR: Method Not Allowed
Response:
```

The 'Response' is empty. When I try a `knife cookbook list`, I get back an empty set. I imagine that's because it's fetching it from the server, which doesn't have the cookbook yet.

I saw [this post](http://wiki.opscode.com/plugins/viewsource/viewpagesrc.action?pageId=7897351) on the old Opscode wiki, which lead me to believe that I'm trying to edit the `_default` environment. So created a Dev environment, confirmed it existed, and:

```
knife cookbook upload getting-started -E Dev
```

Same result. My last resort was to specify an admin account:

```
knife cookbook upload getting-started -E Dev -u admin
```

Same result.

What do I need to do in order to successfully upload this cookbook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue from a default install. Turns out the knife.rb needed https:// instead of http:// in the server url as well.

Comment: Ah! That would explain why the redirect. And getting the hostname (instead of the fqdn) makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I also received this error when I attempted to upload a chef role from a local json file but had properties missing in my local json.  When I used extra verbosity mode I saw that knife was attempting an HTTP PUT operation and received the `HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed` response.

So it seems that the "Method Not Allowed" error basically means that knife submitted an HTTP request that the Chef server did not understand.

To fix my issue with the role, once I used the correct role format (shown below), it worked fine.

```
{
    "name": "my role name",
    "description": "my role description",
    "chef_type": "role",
    "json_class": "Chef::Role",
    "run_list": [ 
              "recipe[recipe1]", 
              "recipe[recipe2]"
           ],
    "default_attributes": {},
    "override_attributes": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "Method Not Allowed" error is actually an [HTTP 405](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) error. I didn't know that. Turns out I had some odd redirection on my Chef server. I would address the server by its FQDN but get redirected to the hostname. I turned on 'extra' verbosity:

```
knife cookbook upload getting-started -V -V
```

And the debug messages let me know that the initial upload was getting an HTTP 301 (Permanently Moved). When knife tried to hit the new address, it would use a GET instead of a POST, causing the 405. I configured knife to point to the redirected URL and the upload was a success.